# Program on ARM cannot find shared library while ldconfig finds it

Tags: linux, arm, shared-libraries, gstreamer

I have compiled my own shared library "libgsttest.so" which I put in /usr/lib/test

```
/usr/lib/test/libgsttest.so
```

I added a file "test.conf" in /etc/ld.so.conf.d containing one line:

```
/usr/lib/test
```

the I run ldconfig. To check whether ldconfig found the library, i run:

```
ldconfig -p | grep test
libgsttest.so (libc6) => /usr/lib/test/libgsttest.so
```

This shared library is used by a gstreamer plugin (but my guess is that that doesn't really matter to the problem). When I start my plugin, linux protests:

```
Could not load plugin file: Opening module failed: libgsttest.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

any ideas why my program cannot find my .so while ldconfig finds it?

EDIT: I have the exact same configuration running on an Opensuse 13.1 with an intel processor where I have no problems!

EDIT 2: some more details on my configuration:

- OpenSuse 13.1 - Intel - 64 bit OS.
- ARM Opensuse 13.1 inside qemu emulation (on the OS mentioned above); so this is not a native arm OS...

EDIT 3: I am sure the library is in the correct format: since putting it in /usr/lib and running ldconfig fixes the problem. The real question remains: why doens't my program find it when it's in the subdir?

Comment: Not necessarily the most efficient solution compared to someone recognizing your problem, but `strace` will show you what actually happens when you try to run this, including what the dynamic linker is doing in terms of searching or load attempts.

Comment: I just tried, but strace is not working within the qemu environment (which is a little unstable unfortunately... yet the gstreamer framework seems to work normally; compilation worked rather fine,...

Comment: Are you absolutely sure this library is in the correct format?  You might want to compare it's installation to that of a working already installed library, use objdump or readelf to compare the file details, etc.

Comment: the libraries on both systems (linux and amd) are made with the exact same sources and makefiles, same includes and headers (since both opensuse 13.1 os)...

Comment: That's not what is of concern; rather, you need to verify that the toolchain is generating appropriate ABI code appropriately identified, that the file is being installed correctly with the correct naming convention, etc.  You can do that by verifying your procedures, but *comparing your library file to one known to work* (ie, an already installed system libary) is a simple way to cross check.

Comment: I edited my question with the extra info: I'm sure the library is in correct format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a workaround which seems to have helped:

I put my library in /usr/lib/ and ran ldconfig --> everything works

I remove my library from /usr/lib --> everything keeps working.

Maybe ldconfig tries to be too smart; and didn't notice any changes in /usr/lib/test/ since it wasn't tracking this folder before. By changing something in /usr/lib/ I might have forced him to do a real refresh?

Answer (score 0):

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html

> ldconfig doesn't set up the linker names; typically this is done
>   during library installation, and the linker name is simply created as
>   a symbolic link to the ``latest'' soname or the latest real name. I
>   would recommend having the linker name be a symbolic link to the
>   soname, since in most cases if you update the library you'd like to
>   automatically use it when linking. I asked H. J. Lu why ldconfig
>   doesn't automatically set up the linker names. His explanation was
>   basically that you might want to run code using the latest version of
>   a library, but might instead want development to link against an old
>   (possibly incompatible) library. Therefore, ldconfig makes no
>   assumptions about what you want programs to link to, so installers
>   must specifically modify symbolic links to update what the linker will
>   use for a library.

Comment: thanks for the info, but I don't see how that's helping me with my problem...?